# cannot connect to MongoDB, Ubuntu 64 VM ( Vagrant, PuPHPet )

Tags: mongodb, vagrant, database-connection, ubuntu-14.04, database

Downloaded and tried a couple of different versions from puphpet.com just to be sure. Here is the mongo part of code from puphpet config.yaml:

```
mongodb:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        auth: 1
        port: '27017'
    databases:
        kxuqYQ6plcMS:
            name: awesome
            user: admin
            password: '1234'
```

IMPORTANT ! I can run mongo in git shell, and mongod service is running, but cannot access it from outside.

mongodb conf :

```
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
port = 27017
auth = 1
```

I've tried commenting the bind_ip, without success. During Robomongo connection i also tried with ssh, specifying

```
SSH_adress = 127.0.0.1:22
username = vagrant
password = vagrant
```

and also authentication, but that does not matter since it cannot connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is probably that you did not add the Mongo port to the firewall section. The port is accessible from inside the VM, but anything outside of it needs to be cleared by iptables.

Just add to the firewall section within your config.yaml

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, i would up vote your answer if i had the reputation. I did the following in Vagrantfile:

`config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 27017, host: 27017`

and commented out the bind_ip of mongodb.conf file

Answer (score 4):

The same was happening to me.
I added the following lines at the end of the Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000 
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 27017, host: 27017
end
```

And changed in ***/etc/mongodb.conf*** bind_ip to **0.0.0.0**

```
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
```

Restarted mongodb and after that I could connect to it through the host and Robomongo

Comment: Sorry did not notice that i did not mark the first answer as correct. Your answer is also correct, but i want to stay fair since the first helped me solve the issue. Btw, take a notice, robomongo won't work on mongodb 3.0+ . Had some issues with that in the past

Comment: Thaaaank you @Marko!
I was getting crazy trying to connect through Robomongo. Tried it with MongoBooster, works like a charm :)